# Adding PayPal to IOS brings up many errors With Facebook SDK

Tags: xcode, swift, paypal

Hello I am attempting to integrate PayPal into my app I added it via cocoa pods and also added the required libraries but now when compiling I get the error:

```
 Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter", referenced from:
  -[PF_Twitter _getLocalTwitterAccountAsync] in ParseTwitterUtils(PF_Twitter.o)
"_FBTokenInformationExpirationDateKey", referenced from:
  -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy cacheTokenInformation:] in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
  -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy expirationDate] in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
  -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy setExpirationDate:] in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
"_FBTokenInformationTokenKey", referenced from:
  -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy accessToken] in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
  -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy setAccessToken:] in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
"_FBTokenInformationUserFBIDKey", referenced from:
  -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy facebookId] in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
  -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy setFacebookId:] in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_ACAccountStore", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in ParseTwitterUtils(PF_Twitter.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBAppCall", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBRequest", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSDKAccessToken", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in ParseFacebookUtilsV4(PFFacebookPrivateUtilities.o)
  objc-class-ref in ParseFacebookUtilsV4(PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider.o)
  objc-class-ref in ParseFacebookUtilsV4(PFFacebookUtils.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSDKApplicationDelegate", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in ParseFacebookUtilsV4(PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSDKLoginManager", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in ParseFacebookUtilsV4(PFFacebookMobileAuthenticationProvider.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSDKSettings", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in ParseFacebookUtilsV4(PFFacebookPrivateUtilities.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSession", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy", referenced from:
  _OBJC_CLASS_$_PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
"_OBJC_METACLASS_$_FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy", referenced from:
  _OBJC_METACLASS_$_PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

does anyone know how I can clear these errors?

Thanks I am using XCODE 7 and swift

Comment: Check if you go to Pods projects, on targets choose ParseFacebookUtils -> Build Settings -> Build Active Architecture Only and set it to No. Build again. Try the same with the other pods.

Comment: that now gives me only two errors of include of non-modular header inside framework module 'FacebookSDK.FBAppLinkResolver'and Could not build module 'FacebookSDK''

Comment: Maybe you can try to delete the pods, make clean on Xcode, install pods again, change the build settings and try again.

Comment: I attempted to redo the entire integration but still the same error is there a bug in the sdk?